# Turtle.goto function only works with two positive coordinates?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

There are no errors when running my code but the problem I think lies with turtle.goto functions. It only works with two positive coordinates. I can't seem to find a problem close to mine and I've tried all the different turtle functions to establish coordinates. I'm not sure what I'm missing or what else to do.

I know this code may seem very sloppy but I'm new to coding and this is just a college class.

```
import turtle
import time

#Asking for the shape
shape = int(input("Would you like a Square or a Circle? Type 1 for Square or 2 for Circle: "))

#Asking for the (x,y) coordinates
coordinate = int(input("Which option would you like your shape to be drawn in? please enter a number 1-4. 1. top left, 2. bottom left, 3. top right, 4. bottom right: "))
color = int(input("What color would you like your pen to be? Input 1 for red, 2 for blue, or 3 for yellow."))

#Executing if statment
if shape == 2:
    if color == 1:
        turtle.pencolor("red")
        turtle.fillcolor("blue")
    elif color == 2:
        turtle.pencolor("blue")
        turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        turtle.pencolor("yellow")
        turtle.fillcolor("red")
        
        
#Determining pensize due to coordinate and establishing coordinate plane
        if coordinate == 1:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.postion(-150,150)
            turtle.pendown()
            Turtle.pensize(3)
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.circle(50)
            turtle.end_fill()
        elif coordinate == 2:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.setpos(-150,-150)
            turtle.pendown()
            Turtle.pensize(3)
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.circle(50)
            turtle.end_fill()
        elif coordinate == 3:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(150,150)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.pensize(3)
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.circle(50)
            turtle.end_fill()
        else:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(150,-150)
            turtle.pendown()
            Turtle.pensize(3)
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.circle(50)
            turtle.end_fill()

#Squares if statement
elif shape == 1:

    if color == 1:
        turtle.fillcolor("red")
        turtle.pencolor("blue")
    elif color == 2:
        turtle.fillcolor("blue")
        turtle.pencolor("yellow")
    else:
        turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
        turtle.pencolor("red")
        
#Determining pensize due to coordinate and establishing coordinate plane
        if coordinate == 1:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(-300,300)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.end_fill()
        elif coordinate == 2:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(-300,-300)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.end_fill()
        elif coordinate == 3:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(300,300)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.end_fill()
        else:
            turtle.penup()
            turtle.goto(300,-300)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.begin_fill()
            turtle.right(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(100)
            turtle.left(90)
            turtle.forward(50)
            turtle.end_fill()

else:
    print("Your shape is not an option.")
```

Comment: if I understand your post correctly, are you asking why turtle.goto function requires two positives coordinates?

Comment: The documentation for turtle.goto clearly state that it has to be [two values](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/turtle.html?highlight=turtle#turtle.goto)  turtle.goto(x, y=None) where x is a number or a pair/vector of numbers

Answer (score 0):

There's no issue with negative coordinates. The indents are incorrect. The shape is only drawn if you choose color=3.

Here is the updated code:

```
import turtle
import time

#Asking for the shape
shape = int(input("Would you like a Square or a Circle? Type 1 for Square or 2 for Circle: "))

#Asking for the (x,y) coordinates
coordinate = int(input("Which option would you like your shape to be drawn in? please enter a number 1-4. 1. top left, 2. bottom left, 3. top right, 4. bottom right: "))
color = int(input("What color would you like your pen to be? Input 1 for red, 2 for blue, or 3 for yellow."))

#Executing if statment
if shape == 2:
    if color == 1:
        turtle.pencolor("red")
        turtle.fillcolor("blue")
    elif color == 2:
        turtle.pencolor("blue")
        turtle.fillcolor("yellow")
    else:
        turtle.pencolor("yellow")
        turtle.fillcolor("red")
        
        
#Determining pensize due to coordinate and establishing coordinate plane
    if coordinate == 1:   # shifted left to align with 'if color`
        turtle.penup()
        turtle.postion(-150,150)
        turtle.pendown()
        Turtle.pensize(3)
        turtle.begin_fill()
        turtle.circle(50)
        turtle.end_fill()
 ...........
```